# Breeze/Angular: how to prime data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze

I try to primeData before the GUI binding (like in Papa, John's CodeCamperJumpStart), but I can't make it work.

Here is my code in datacontext.js:

```
function primeData() {
    Q.all([getLookups()]);
};
function getLookups() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Lookups");
    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(succeeded);

    function succeeded(data) {
        return data.results[0];
    }
}
```

However, Q.all() doesn't seem to put the call wait for succeeded to occur first. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The call to Q.all is happening, but nobody is waiting for its promise to return. So when you run primeData from somewhere, the code right after it (which you do not show) will just continue on.

But I think your question is more around the .then in the getLookups ... for that, since you are using Breeze, you need to look into the to$q method, which converts Q to $q (which is what Angular wants)

Comment: Actually, John, I just watched your new video on breeze/angular and found how to use to$q. However, based on my testing, I don't see any difference. Did I miss anything?